# Magento - Add to cart button missing in configurable products

Tags: magento

We have a small issue here .Magento1.9.2.

we had set the minimum order qty in SYS>Inventory
as 1 . After that , all **Newly created**  CONFIGURABLE PRODUCTS are not displaying Size Swatch, QTY button or ADD TO CART button in products page . We had reindex all the data . Still it did not change . We have now set the Minimum Order Quantity back as 0 (zero)
Even after that , the newly created configurable products are not showing Size Swatch or ADD TO CART button .

Qty Button and ADD TO CART button appears for Simple Products .

Please let me know what's to be done ..thanks

Screen Shot enclosed

[image]

```js
    //<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
      if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;

        if (url) {
         form.action = url;
       }
       var e = null;
       try {
        this.form.submit();
      } catch (e) {
      }
      this.form.action = oldUrl;
      if (e) {
        throw e;
      }

      if (button && button != 'undefined') {
        button.disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

  productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
    if(this.validator) {
      var nv = Validation.methods;
      delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
      delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
      delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                  if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                  }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                  if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                  }
                  this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
              }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
```

Hope the info helps . Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: please post your code in the content , don't use images it won't be useful for us ,thanks

Comment: check those simple products are in stock and enabled.

Comment: Simple products are IN STOCK and enabled. All older configurable products are seen with size swatch , qty button and ADD TO CART button. When we use the same attributes  for adding new configurable products , it is not showing the buttons.

Comment: check for "default theme" , also check what changes you done by comparing inititial theme files. enable template path hints for check file path.